# Robocopy in TFS Build PowerShell Step Reports Failure But Has No Error

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, robocopy

My powershell script runs without error reported in the log file, but the TFS 2015 build step reports an error. Do I need to perform a special call back?

This is a new style build, not a XAML based one.

The script is nothing special, it calls robocopy, which occurs successfully.

Here's the script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [string]$localWorkspace,
  [string]$destination 
)
begin{}
process
{
  try
  {
    ## Script
    $ServiceDirs = Get-ChildItem $localWorkspace -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -eq $True -and $_.Name -match "^Service$" } | % { $_.FullName }

    $serviceCollection = @{}
    foreach ($Service in $ServiceDirs)
    {
      $ServiceName = Get-ChildItem $Service | ?{$_.Name -match ".*\.csproj$" } | % { $_.BaseName }

      $binpath = ($service + "\bin\release")
      $serviceCollection.Add($serviceName , $binpath)
    }

    $serviceCollection.GetEnumerator() | % { 
      Write-Verbose "Processing service: $($_.key)" 

      $currentDestination = ($destination + "\" + $_.key)
      $output = robocopy $_.value $currentDestination /MIR /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /nc /ns /np
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    write-host "Caught an exception:" 
    write-host "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)" 
    write-host "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" 
  }
}
end{}
```

I can see all the robocopy output, if I unsilence it and use /DEBUG and none of the catch in the TFS build log.

Strangely, when I force an error, the catch executes and the step reports success.

The error message reported is:

> Task PowerShell failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs
>   for the task for more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR** Check the exit codes used in the calls, or use `exit` to leave the 
script.

---

[RoboCopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) uses a suite of exit codes including:

> 0×00   0       No errors occurred, and no copying was done.
>                      The source and destination directory trees are completely synchronized.
>
> 0×01   1       One or more files were copied successfully (that is, new files have arrived).

<sub>([Full List Here](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html))</sub>

Because the script didn't have an `exit` statement the value of `$LastExitCode` was 1 which makes sense for Robocopy but causes TFS to believe the script to fail.

Using `exit` supressed the Robocopy exit code so TFS believed the script to have worked. However, this meant that any Robocopy information was being suppressed.

Changing the final line to `exit ($LastExitCode -band 24)` solved the issue properly, as per [this article](https://gist.github.com/grenade/8686388).